# Переход к текущей позиции пользователя

Tags: swift, yandexmapkit

разрабатываю приложение на основе Yandex MapKit(Swift) и встала необходимость сделать кнопку перехода камеры к текущей позиции пользователя (как в том же приложении Яндекс карт). Так и не могу понять как это реализовать, буду благодарен любым советам

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так:

```
userLocationLayer = mapView.mapWindow.map.userLocationLayer
userLocationLayer.isEnabled = true
userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true

mapView.mapWindow.map.addCameraListener(with: self)
```

Посмотрите мой пример здесь: https://github.com/varton86/YandexMapTest

Comment: Склонировал ваш репозиторий, и как раз на самый интересных для меня местах ошибки: `userLocationLayer` have no member `isEnabled` и вторая связанная с этим фрагментом `userLocationLayer = mapView.mapWindow.map.userLocationLayer`.  Буду рад, если поможете с ними разобраться

Comment: В библиотеке Яндекса изменились методы. Я обновил pod, поправил вызовы и залил на github, попробуйте еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnGoToMe = findViewById(R.id.navigationArrow);
btnGoToMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mapView.getMap().move(
                        new CameraPosition(userLocationLayer.cameraPosition().getTarget(), 15.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                        new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                        null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]